# If $\psi(q,Q,t) = \sum_i F_i(q,t)Q_i + G(q,t)$ show that $\dfrac{\partial F_\alpha}{\partial q_\beta} = \dfrac{\partial F_\beta}{\partial q_\alpha}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A function $\psi = \psi(q,Q,t)$ defined to satisfy

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial Q_\alpha\partial Q_\beta} = 0,\\
\sum_\beta \dfrac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial q_\beta\partial Q_\alpha}Q_\beta + \dfrac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial t \partial Q_\alpha} - \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial Q_\alpha} = 0$$

(with $\alpha,\beta=1,...,n$ and $Q = \dfrac{dq}{dt}$) has the form
$$\psi(q,Q,t) = \sum_i F_i(q,t)Q_i + G(q,t).$$

I want to prove that given the linearity in $Q$ of $\psi$ we have

$$\dfrac{\partial F_\alpha}{\partial q_\beta} = \dfrac{\partial F_\beta}{\partial q_\alpha} \tag{1}$$

I don't even know how to tackle this problem. $n=2$ and $F_1 = q_1t + 2q_2t^2$, $F_2 = q_1^2 + q_2^3$ wouldn't be a counterexample? (it shouldn't be because this is a very important theorem in classical mechanics, see Jose and Saletan - Classical Dynamics, A contemporary approach page 67, referring to problem 4). Note that if $n=1$ the statement is obvious.

Also note that if (1) is true then $F_\alpha = \dfrac{\partial\Phi(q,t)}{\partial q_\alpha}$, and $G = \dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$, which is the ultimate result of the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in Jose & Saletan, you have to use that $\psi$, being a difference of two Lagrangians, solves the Lagriangian equation (2.29) in J&S. As you noticed, the multidimensional version of (2.32) therein is the statement that
\begin{equation}
 \psi = \left<F(q,t),\dot{q}\right> + G(q,t). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Here, $F$ is an $n$-vector, and $G$ is a scalar.
Furthermore, you know that $\psi$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}} \dot{q} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \dot{q} \partial t} - \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q} = 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Here, $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}}$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, because both $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are $n$-dimensional variables. Both $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \dot{q} \partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q}$ are $n$-vectors. Of course, you can write this out in component notation, but I prefer the above notation. Note that the term $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}} \dot{q}$ in $(2)$ describes the $n \times n$ matrix $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}}$ multiplying the $n$-vector $\dot{q}$, so the result is the $n$-vector $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}} \dot{q}$.

From $(1)$, we see that
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} \dot{q} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial q} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \dot{q}} = F(q,t). \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Note that since $F$ is an $n$-vector which itself depends on the $n$-dimensional quantity $q$, the partial derivative $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Based on $(3)$, we can now calculate
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial \dot{q} \partial t} =  \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t \partial \dot{q}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}. \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Using the expressions found in $(3)$ and $(4)$ in $(2)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} \dot{q} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} - \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial q} \dot{q} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial q}\right) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial G}{\partial q} = 0, \tag{5}
\end{equation}
which is exactly the same as (2.33) in J&S.

Now, we have the equation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial q}.
\end{equation}
Taking the derivative to $q$ on both sides yields

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial q\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial q^2}.
\end{equation}
On the right hand side, we have the *symmetric* matrix $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial q^2}$, i.e. the Hessian of $G$. That means that the matrix on the left hand side must also be symmetric. In other words (written in components),
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 F_\alpha}{\partial q_\beta \partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 F_\beta}{\partial q_\alpha \partial t}.
\end{equation}
Integrating on both sides to $t$ gives the required condition, up to a constant; the only thing left is to argue why this constant should be zero.